# setOnClickListener not fired on Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, clicklistener

I'm trying to put a click listener on a ConstraintLayout but it's never fired.
I don't know why I tried to look about `android:clickable` but I didn't get any better

This is what I have in my parent view:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/search_scanner"
    layout="@layout/scan_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

The layout scan_button is the following:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scan_layout"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scan_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_registration_social_networks"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
            android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/scan_button_image"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_scan"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/scan_book"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/scan_book_text"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:lines="2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scan_button"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is what I'm doing about the listener:

```
search_scanner.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(context, ScannerActivity::class.java))
}
```

If you have some answers about it, I'll be glad!

**EDIT :**
I **solved** it ! I just add an elevation on my layout because the scan layout was at the same level with a ListView (either the listview was empty). So it's working !

Thanks guys for your help

Comment: Remove `android:id="@+id/scan_layout"` and set `clickListener` on `search_scanner`

Comment: Hello, I already tried this but nothing is fired :/

Comment: Where are you including this layout? And put a log statement in the `onClick` function.

Comment: its fragment or activity?

Comment: I'm including this layout in a fragment.
When I click on my Layout nothing is fired so I don't get any log about it.

Comment: @ThomasCoutard i did run your code in activity it runs fine and I could get toast for onclick which means click is triggered just try if it works in activity though it should work either way

Comment: and just confirmed it works in fragment too I think there is some other issue just put a toast